# Listbox Selection to Textbox

Tags: listbox, google-apps-script, textfield

I have a ListBox that is populated from a spreadsheet filled with teacher's names and phone extensions. I want to be able to select a teacher's name and have it populate the textbox with the teacher's phone extension automatically. I have found several ways to do it via C++ but none using Google Apps Script...

```
          //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
          var vrtMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtMainPanel');

          //Create Spreadsheet Source
          var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
          var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
          var spSubjectList = spSheet.getSheetByName('SubjectList');
          var spPeriodList = spSheet.getSheetByName('PeriodList');
          var spCountList = spSheet.getSheetByName('CountList');

          //Create the form elements
          var hdlExt = app.createServerHandler('getExt').addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
          var hdlTeacherName = app.createServerHandler('getTeacherName').addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
          var lbxTeacherName = app.createListBox().setId('lbxTeacherName').setName('lbxTeacherName').addChangeHandler(hdlExt).addChangeHandler(hdlTeacherName);
          var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,1,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
              lstTeacherNames.sort();

              for (var l = 0; l < lstTeacherNames.length; l++) {
                lbxTeacherName.addItem(lstTeacherNames[l],l);
              }

          var lblTeacherName = app.createLabel('Teacher Name:');
          var txtTeacherName = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTeacherName').setId('txtTeacherName').setVisible(false);

          var lblExt = app.createLabel('Ext:');
          var txtExt = app.createTextBox().setName('txtExt').setId('txtExt');

       //Set DateBox to Tomorrow's Date
          var tomorrow =new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));// set hours, min, sec & milliSec to 0 and day=day+1
          Logger.log(tomorrow);
          var lblDate = app.createLabel('Date of Test:');
          var boxDate = app.createDateBox().setId('boxDate').setName('boxDate').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT).setValue(tomorrow);

          var lbxSubject = app.createListBox().setId('lbxSubject').setName('lbxSubject');
          var lstSubjects = spSubjectList.getRange(1,1,spSubjectList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
              lstSubjects.sort();

              for (var l = 0; l < lstSubjects.length; l++) {
                lbxSubject.addItem(lstSubjects[l]);
              }

          var lbxPeriod = app.createListBox().setId('lbxPeriod').setName('lbxPeriod');
          var lstPeriods = spPeriodList.getRange(1,1,spPeriodList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
              lstPeriods.sort();

              for (var l = 0; l < lstPeriods.length; l++) {
                lbxPeriod.addItem(lstPeriods[l]);
              }

          var lblStudentNum = app.createLabel('Number of Students:');
          var lbxStudentNum = app.createListBox().setId('lbxStudentNum').setName('lbxStudentNum');
          var lstStudentNums = spCountList.getRange(1,1,spCountList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
              lstStudentNums.sort();

              for (var l = 0; l < lstStudentNums.length; l++) {
                lbxStudentNum.addItem(lstStudentNums[l]);
              }

          var txtSourceGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtSourceGrp').setVisible(false);
          var txtTypeGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTypeGrp').setVisible(false);
          var txtElementsID = app.createTextBox().setName('txtElementsID').setText('Elements Test ID').setVisible(false);
          var txtQuiaLink = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaLink').setText('Quia Test Link').setVisible(false);
          var txtQuiaPass = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaPass').setText('Quia Test Passphrase').setVisible(false);

          //Create Source Radio Button Group
          var radHCopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Hard-Copy'));
          var radECopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Electronic-Copy'));

          //Create Type Radio Button Group
          var radTExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Teacher-Made Exam'));
          var radEExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Elements Exam'));
          var radQExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Quia Exam'));

          var btnCreate = app.createButton('Create Event');

          //Client Handlers for textBoxes
          var showTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(true);
          var hideTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(false);
              radEExam.addClickHandler(showTxtElementHandler);
              radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);
              radQExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);


          var showTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(true);
          var hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(false);
              radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
              radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
              radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);

          var showTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(true);
          var hideTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(false);
              radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaPassHandler);
              radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);
              radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);

          //Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
          var evtHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
              evtHandler.addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);

          //Add this handler to the button
              btnCreate.addClickHandler(evtHandler);

          //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
          var formGrid = app.createGrid(12,3).setCellPadding(3);
          vrtMainPanel.add(formGrid);
          formGrid
          .setWidget(0,0,lbxTeacherName)
          .setWidget(0,1,txtExt)
          .setWidget(0,2,txtTeacherName)
          .setWidget(1,0,lbxPeriod)
          .setWidget(1,1,lbxSubject)
          .setWidget(2,0,lblDate)
          .setWidget(2,1,boxDate)
          .setWidget(3,0,lblStudentNum)
          .setWidget(3,1,lbxStudentNum)
          .setWidget(4,0,radHCopy)
          .setWidget(4,1,radECopy)
          .setWidget(5,0,radTExam)
          .setWidget(6,0,radEExam)
          .setWidget(6,1,txtElementsID)
          .setWidget(7,0,radQExam)
          .setWidget(7,1,txtQuiaLink)
          .setWidget(8,1,txtQuiaPass)
          .setWidget(9,0,txtSourceGrp)
          .setWidget(9,1,txtTypeGrp)
          .setWidget(10,0,btnCreate)

          //Add this panel to the application
          app.add(vrtMainPanel);

          //Return the application
          return app;
        }

        function getExt(e){
          var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
          var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
          var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,2,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
          var txtExt = app.getElementById('txtExt');
              txtExt.setText(lstTeacherNames[Number(e.parameter.lbxTeacherName)][0]);// we get the value in the 2D array returned by getValues()
          return app;
        }

        function getTeacherName(e){
          var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
          var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
          var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,1,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
          var txtTeacherName = app.getElementById('txtTeacherName');
              txtTeacherName.setText(lstTeacherNames[e.parameter.lbxTeacherName][0]);// we get the value in the 2D array returned by getValues()
          return app;
        }

// CREATE EVENT FUNCTION

function createEvents(e){
  //Get the active application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  try{
    //Get the entries
    var ssTeacher = e.parameter.txtTeacherName;
    var ssExt = e.parameter.txtExt;
    var ssSubject = e.parameter.lbxSubject;
    var ssPeriod = e.parameter.lbxPeriod;
    var ssStudentNum = e.parameter.lbxStudentNum;
    var ssSource = e.parameter.txtSourceGrp;
    var ssType = e.parameter.txtTypeGrp;
    var ssElementsID = e.parameter.txtElementsID;
    var ssQuiaLink = e.parameter.txtQuiaLink;
    var ssQuiaPass = e.parameter.txtQuiaPass;
    var eventDate = e.parameter.boxDate;
    var eventCalSubject = ssPeriod + ": " + ssTeacher + " (" + ssStudentNum + ")";
    var eventCalDetails = "Extension: " + ssExt + "\n" +
          "Subject: " + ssSubject + "\n\n" +
          "Source: " + ssSource + "\n" +
          "Type: " + ssType + "\n" +
          "Elements ID: " + ssElementsID + "\n" +
          "Quia Test Link: " + ssQuiaLink + "\n" +
          "Quia Passphrase: " + ssQuiaPass;

    //Get the calendar
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('davie.k12.nc.us_d2mv2eb8aspuant1vb5j6r3sis@group.calendar.google.com');//Change the calendar id
    //Create the events
    var newID = cal.createAllDayEvent(eventCalSubject, eventDate, {description:eventCalDetails}).getId();

    //Log the entries in a spreadsheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc').getActiveSheet();//Change the spreadhseet key to yours
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 13).setValues([[new Date(),eventDate,ssTeacher,ssExt,ssSubject,ssPeriod,ssSource,ssType,ssElementsID,ssQuiaLink,ssQuiaPass,ssStudentNum,newID]]);
    return app;

    //Show the confirmation message
    app.add(app.createLabel('Kurzweil Calendar Event created successfully...'));
    //Make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('vertMainPanel').setVisible(false);
    return app;
  }

  //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
  catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+ e));
    return app;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide a small code with a doGet that reproduce the simplified configuration please ? This would spare us the time to write it from scratch. Thanks - PS it would be quite simple in a server handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my first comment you have to create a server Handler to get that but your script would need a few minor modifications :

1. The listBox must be modified to return a numeric index instead of a name, this will simplify the process of getting the right data on the spreadsheet (when `addItem(arg1,arg2)` has 2 arguments the first one is shown while the second is returned to the handler function >> you'll have to modify your other handler functions in consequence, use the same principle I used in the `getPhone(e)` function)
2. the Labels that you created where not visible so I changed the grid values
3. The way you get data in this new version right from the spreadsheet is really a good idea, I regret I didn't think about it myself ;-)
4. keep in mind that values returned by `e.parameter.varName` are strings, that's why I used `Number(e.parameter.lbxTeacherName)` to get the value in the spreadsheet data.
5. I assumed that the phone extensions where in column B on the teacher data sheet... if not modify accordingly in the `getPhone` handler function.

(edit : I changed the "tomorrow" definition to skip string manipulation but it's a detail)

Here is the full modified code :

```
    function doGet() {
      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

      //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
      var vrtMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtMainPanel');

      //Create Spreadsheet Source
      var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
      var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
      var spSubjectList = spSheet.getSheetByName('SubjectList');
      var spPeriodList = spSheet.getSheetByName('PeriodList');
      var spCountList = spSheet.getSheetByName('CountList');

      //Create the form elements
      var lblTeacherName = app.createLabel('Teacher Name:');
      var teacherNameHandler = app.createServerHandler('getPhone').addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
      var lbxTeacherName = app.createListBox().setId('lbxTeacherName').setName('lbxTeacherName').addChangeHandler(teacherNameHandler);
      var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,1,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstTeacherNames.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstTeacherNames.length; l++) {
            lbxTeacherName.addItem(lstTeacherNames[l],l);
          }

      var lblExt = app.createLabel('Ext:');
      var txtExt = app.createTextBox().setName('txtExt').setId('txtExt');

   //Set DateBox to Tomorrow's Date
      var tomorrow =new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));// set hours, min, sec & milliSec to 0 and day=day+1
      Logger.log(tomorrow);
      var lblDate = app.createLabel('Date:');
      var boxDate = app.createDateBox().setId('boxDate').setName('boxDate').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT).setValue(tomorrow);

      var lbxSubject = app.createListBox().setId('lbxSubject').setName('lbxSubject');
      var lstSubjects = spSubjectList.getRange(1,1,spSubjectList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstSubjects.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstSubjects.length; l++) {
            lbxSubject.addItem(lstSubjects[l]);
          }

      var lbxPeriod = app.createListBox().setId('lbxPeriod').setName('lbxPeriod');
      var lstPeriods = spPeriodList.getRange(1,1,spPeriodList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstPeriods.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstPeriods.length; l++) {
            lbxPeriod.addItem(lstPeriods[l]);
          }

      var lblStudentNum = app.createLabel('Number of Students:');
      var lbxStudentNum = app.createListBox().setId('lbxStudentNum').setName('lbxStudentNum');
      var lstStudentNums = spCountList.getRange(1,1,spCountList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstStudentNums.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstStudentNums.length; l++) {
            lbxStudentNum.addItem(lstStudentNums[l]);
          }

      var txtSourceGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtSourceGrp').setVisible(false);
      var txtTypeGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTypeGrp').setVisible(false);
      var txtElementsID = app.createTextBox().setName('txtElementsID').setText('Elements Test ID').setVisible(false);
      var txtQuiaLink = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaLink').setText('Quia Test Link').setVisible(false);
      var txtQuiaPass = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaPass').setText('Quia Test Passphrase').setVisible(false);

      //Create Source Radio Button Group
      var radHCopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Hard-Copy'));
      var radECopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Electronic-Copy'));

      //Create Type Radio Button Group
      var radTExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Teacher-Made Exam'));
      var radEExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Elements Exam'));
      var radQExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Quia Exam'));

      var btnCreate = app.createButton('Create Event');

      //Client Handlers for textBoxes
      var showTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(false);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(showTxtElementHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);


      var showTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(false);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);

      var showTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(false);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaPassHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);

      //Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
      var evtHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
          evtHandler.addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);

      //Add this handler to the button
          btnCreate.addClickHandler(evtHandler);

      //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
      var formGrid = app.createGrid(12,2).setCellPadding(3);
      vrtMainPanel.add(formGrid);
      formGrid
      .setWidget(0,0,lblTeacherName)
      .setWidget(1,0,lbxTeacherName)
      .setWidget(0,1,lblExt)
      .setWidget(1,1,txtExt)
      .setWidget(2,0,lbxPeriod)
      .setWidget(2,1,lbxSubject)
      .setWidget(3,0,lblDate)
      .setWidget(3,1,boxDate)
      .setWidget(4,0,lblStudentNum)
      .setWidget(4,1,lbxStudentNum)
      .setWidget(5,0,radHCopy)
      .setWidget(5,1,radECopy)
      .setWidget(6,0,radTExam)
      .setWidget(7,0,radEExam)
      .setWidget(7,1,txtElementsID)
      .setWidget(8,0,radQExam)
      .setWidget(8,1,txtQuiaLink)
      .setWidget(9,1,txtQuiaPass)
      .setWidget(10,0,txtSourceGrp)
      .setWidget(10,1,txtTypeGrp)
      .setWidget(11,0,btnCreate)

      //Add this panel to the application
      app.add(vrtMainPanel);

      //Return the application
      return app;
    }

    function getPhone(e){
      var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
      var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
      var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,2,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var txtExt = app.getElementById('txtExt');
      txtExt.setText(lstTeacherNames[Number(e.parameter.lbxTeacherName)][0]);// we get the value in the 2D array returned by getValues() 
      return app;
    }
```

---

**EDIT : following your last comment.**

Although the method you used to retrieve the teacher's name is excellent (and I guess indeed that I'd have chosen the same approach ) there is another way to achieve it which is less obvious but much more efficient in terms of "number of code lines" .

The trick it to store the teacher name as a TAG on the extension phone number and to retrieve it from there in the `createEvent()` handler.
The code needs only a very minor modification (get 2 columns of data from the SS and assign a value to the tag+get that value - see comments in code) so I won't reproduce the whole thing, just the relevant part below :

```
function getPhone(e){
  var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnqSFd3iikE3dEtBQndOYVNEbFVWcDlyQmFoaUV3a1E');
  var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
  var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,1,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),2).getValues();// get 2 columns instead of only one
  Logger.log(lstTeacherNames);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var txtExt = app.getElementById('txtExt');
  txtExt.setText(lstTeacherNames[Number(e.parameter.lbxTeacherName)][1]);// set the phone number 
  txtExt.setTag(lstTeacherNames[Number(e.parameter.lbxTeacherName)][0]);// set teacher's name in the TAG
  return app;
}


function createEvents(e){
  //Get the active application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    //Get the entries
    var ssTeacher = e.parameter.txtExt_tag;
  Logger.log('teacher = '+ssTeacher)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, I think it will help with my other issue as well. I will have to play with some code and see. I also changed my Date code... it works like a charm.

Comment: In the getPhone function it sets lbxTeacherName to a number value of the array... is there anyway to have the string value (the name) go to the spreadsheet instead of the number value that is returned by the array?

Comment: Not sure I understand...what number?  Where does it write to the SS?

Comment: I have that code separate from the code above... but when I tell the program to get e.parameter.lbxTeacherName, it now pulls a number instead of the name to the spreadsheet. How can I get the selected value as a string (name) before it is changed to a number?

Comment: I explained the process in point 1 in the answer, the returned number ils the index in the spreadsheet:because I used 2 arguments in the list.add item(). Use the same process to get back the string values as I did in this function.

Comment: I modified the code in my original post to get the Teacher's name to be returned so that I could reference when creating an event or sending information to the spreadsheet. Is that the best way to accomplish it or should I have done something different?

Comment: That's exactly what should be done... You could have integrate the code in the createEvent function but a separate function will make it easier to read and to maintain. Moreover you will be able to use your function from any other one if ever you need it. All in all I guess you made the best choice :-)

Comment: I had another idea, not bad I think !! test it and tell me what you think ;-)

Comment: That worked great as well and I think I like it a little better, although I am glad that I setup the other correctly.  Thanks for your help with this project.